# has_many :through child and parent validations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 3.0
has_many :X, :through => :something set up and i have a custom validator that does some custom validation on some complicated logic. I want to when you add anything to this many to many relationship both models are valid?

Project Class:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments

  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

Assignment:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User class with custom validator:

```
class MyCustomValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate( record )
    if record.projects.length > 3
      record.errors[:over_worked] = "you have to many projects!"
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :projects, :through => :assignments

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates_with MyCustomValidator
end
```

What i really want to do is prevent each model from invalidating the other so to say 
prevent

```
my_user.projects << fourth_project
```

and

```
my_project.users << user_with_four_projects_already
```

from happening. Right now it allows the assignment and just the user becomes invalid.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates_associated :users
end
```

According to the docs, users must already be assigned to Projects in order to be validated.  So:

```
my_user.projects << fourth_project
```

would occur, then projects would validate the user and see that it is indeed invalid, making the project invalid as well as in the inverse example.

Comment: fyi, another way you could do this is to user accepts_nested_attributes_for which, iirc, already validates the associated object and you can pass in an option of :limit => 3

Comment: irb(main):001:0> bob = User.find(1)
=> #<User id: 1, name: "bob">
irb(main):002:0> bob.projects
=> [#<Project id: 1, name: "project1">, #<Project id: 2, name: "project2">, #<Project id: 3, name: "project3">]
irb(main):003:0> bob.valid?
=> true
irb(main):004:0> project4 = Project.find(4)
=> #<Project id: 4, name: "project4">
irb(main):005:0> project4.users
=> []
irb(main):006:0> project4.users << bob
=> [#<User id: 1, name: "bob">]
irb(main):007:0> project4.valid?
=> true
irb(main):008:0> bob.valid?
=> true

Comment: Oops, when i reload it becomes more bizare
irb(main):009:0> project4.save
=> true
irb(main):010:0> project4.reload
=> #<Project id: 4, name: "project4">
irb(main):011:0> project4.valid?
=> false
irb(main):012:0> bob.reload
=> #<User id: 1, name: "bob">
irb(main):013:0> bob.valid?
=> false

Comment: Err sorry for the bad post, this appears to work kind of, i think eager loading is somehow screwing me. If you don't call user.projects before the assignment on assignment << it is invalid without needing to reload. bizarre. Thanks

Comment: again, you may want to try accepts_nested_attributes_for if it fits with what you are doing.  the bonus is that you get to set the limit without the custom validation

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this, and I would appreciate your opinion but this seemed to work (granted it's just reloading)
   has_many :users, :through => :assignments, :after_add => :evaluate_user
    def evaluate_user(user)
    user.reload
    user
   end